# XSL global value assignment

Tags: xslt

i have declare one XSL variable

I wanted to chage value of that variable dynamically

ex. var X = 0

if i wanted to reassing X = 100.

It only assign first value to variable , how can i do that in XSL for global assignment of values?

Answer (score 1):

XSL "variables" are in fact not variable at all, they are always assigned when they are defined and keep their value for the duration of their lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:variable>`s are actually constants, you can't change them.  If you see one inside a for-each loop, for example, a variable is actually being defined every time the loop runs, not changed.

You may want to check out parameters. They only work in certain situations, but you can pass a value into a template (either with `call-template` or `apply-templates`) with a parameter, sort of like you would a variable.

[Here is some info](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_with-param.asp)