# Using Global variable

Tags: xslt

This is my portion of xml input.

```
<w:tc> 
   first 
</w:tc> 
<w:tc> 
   second 
</w:tc>
```

I am using xslt1.0 and my template is

```
<xsl:template match="tc"> 
  <!-- When the first match occurs, i am setting a value for a 
       global variable and when the template matches for second time, 
       i have to fetch the value from that variable -->  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In XSLT how do I increment a global variable from a different scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833118/in-xslt-how-do-i-increment-a-global-variable-from-a-different-scope)

Answer (score 0):

> When the first match occurs, i am
>   setting a value for a global variable

This is not possible.

See answers to these similar questions:

- [In XSLT how do I increment a global variable from a different scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833118/)
- [if defined in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291188/)
- [Actually XSLT Lookup (Store variables during loop and use in it another template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752946/)
- [In XSLT how do I increment a global variable from a different scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833118/)
- [XSL global value assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879375/)

Comment: So, this would be a duplicate?

Comment: @Alejandro: Probably, yes - in its current state. If the OP adds specific question, a better answer than "not possible" could be written - one that could stand on its own.

Comment: We already have some experience with [@vignesh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/514227/vignesh)'s questions...

Comment: @Alejandro: I see. Very well. I've voted to close as a duplicate.